# How can I extract text from Win8 print driver generated PostScript file

Tags: ghostscript, postscript, pdftotext

I can extract text from a Win7 print driver generated PostScript file, but not from Win8.

For example, creating some text in Windows' "Notepad", telling Notepad to print using an HP PostScript print driver, and telling the print driver to output to a file, I obtain a file that I then want to extract text from.

I have tried Ghostscript's `ps2ascii` and `pstopdf | pdftotext` and a number of other things on a Ubuntu platform, and while some of these work on the Win7 output, I can not find any combination that work on the Win8 output.

Is there an Open Source solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot guarantee getting text from any PostScript program, its not designed for that.

However Ghostscript's txtwrite device will do a decent job on the output from the Windows PostScript printer driver. Its much better than ps2ascii because (amongst other things) it can handle Unicode, so its not limited to ASCII.

Beware that applications may generate PostScript themselves, so even if the output **appears** to be from the Windows PostScript printer driver, the actual content might be generated by the application.

Also you will only get text out of the Windows PostScript printer driver if the application actually writes text to the device context. For example if you print a PDF from the Edge browser then you will get text in the output. If you print the same PDF from Chrome on the same system, then the text is instead rendered as vectors (ie line, arc, stroke fill etc) not text.

Just be aware that what you are trying to do isn't going to be 100% successful in the general case.

Comment: I am asking about _the_ **specific** **use** **case** using the **Windows** **application** **Notepad** on the Windows 8 platform using a Windows 8 print driver to generate a postscript file. I can get it to work on Windows 7, but not on windows 8 or 10.

Comment: Well, you haven't even posted an example file, nor did you explicitly say that this was your use case, you used it as an example, therefore I couched my reply in general terms.. As I said above, the Ghostscript txtwrite device should be able to do a decent job with this. Although since you have the text file already, I can't really see the point in making a PostScript file from it and then pulling the text back out again.

Comment: Its also possible MS and some printer vendors have changed the Windows print driver for some devices in Windows 8+, its certainly the case that the print pipeline is altered significantly (to use XPS). You might well do better to print to the Microsoft XPS writer and then use GhostsXPS and the txtwrite device to extract the text (you will need to use the most recent GhostXPS release for this to work). As I implied above, post an PostScript example file if you want people to look at this, not everyone has access to/wants to use Windows 8 or above.